# How to adjust component's size according to the screen ( or display ) size?

Tags: java-me, resolution, lwuit

I tested my application in another mobile phone , a `htc` mobile phone , and it has a very large screen size. So I was very surprised when I saw the arrangement of the components ! Here is the captured image of the screen from the camera of another phone :

[image]

So how to make the components be sized and placed well according to the screen display size of any device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIF LWUIT components automatically resized based on resolution. I think you are using `setMargin` or `setPadding` for those components. So you need to handle them based on resolution. Get the resolution for the mobile and change the component margin and padding. use this code for get resolutions,

```
int screen_width = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
int screen_height = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();
```

Comment: Correct, he also used setPreferredSize to a hardcoded value which obviously forces LWUIT to ignore automatic layout. I suggest using the GUI builder and going over the many samples, the GUI builder samples really help with visualizing layout management for multiple resolutions.